# Changing Login Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a member only area for my website and naturally, this requires the user to log in.
The problem is that the plugin did not come with a custom login page. so when someone tries to access this page, they are then directed to 'mysite.com/wp-login.php'

I have added custom login plugins in the hope that they would override the redirect but no joy.

I am intending on changing the wp-login slug to something else for security reasons and would like the plugin to redirect users to a different login page.

I have been searching online and cannot find anything, only redirects after login. I have also raised the question on the plugin authors support page and got no reply

I was hoping someone here could help.

The plugin I am using is called WP Customer Area.

So basically, to summarise...

I would like the plugin to stop directing customers to 'mysite.com/wp-login.php' and instead change it to something like **'mysite.com/customer-login'**.

code I believe handles the redirect

```
public function login_then_redirect_to_url($redirect_to = '')
    {
        $login_url = apply_filters('cuar/routing/login-url', null, $redirect_to);
        if ($login_url == null) {
            $login_url = wp_login_url($redirect_to);
        }

        wp_redirect($login_url);
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the part of the code in the plugin that handles this?

Comment: @Adam after looking through various files (there are over 700 in this plugin) I believe I may have found the code... added above

Comment: There are several plugins that can be used to do this (so you don't have to try and code your own): https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/ or https://wordpress.org/plugins/wps-hide-login/

Comment: @disinfor yeah, Ive seen them, in the past I have used both plugins and my own code. However, that is what I am planning on doing, but first, I need to stop the customer area plugin from directing people to that page and redirect them elsewhere

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve the issue by amending the `wp_login_url($redirect_to);`

I added the below code to functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'login_url', 'my_login_page', 10, 3 );
function my_login_page( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ) {
    return home_url( '/my-login-page/?redirect_to=' . $redirect );
}
```